# Обработка исключений. Правильно ли я делаю?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, try-catch

Есть метод класса `Account` для ввода процента. Если число нормальное, то возвращаем её, иначе выводим сообщение? И правильно ли я делаю?

```
double Account::ReadPercent()
{
    double per;
    try {
        std::cin >> per;
        if (per < 0 || per>100)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("This is a invalid value!\n");
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    return per;
}
```

Comment: У вас в любом случает возвращается считанное число, даже если оно не подходит. Можно try блок засунуть в бесконечный цикл, а return поставить после if.

Comment: не правильно. Если же вы сразу  обрабатываете исключение, то смысль его генерирования пропадает. И не  std::logic_error, а  std::range_error

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы бы оформили сразу ответом.

Comment: @Harry, оформляйте, пожалуйста ответ сами.  Вы лучше излогаете

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения, так скажем механики, вы делаете правильно. Исключение брошено - исключение обработано.
Однако с точки зрения логики, в данном случае, использование не совсем верно. Пользователь вводит процент, если процент неправильный, то функция выведет в консоль текст "Некорректное значение" и вернет значение per, которое было введено. Более правильно было бы заставить пользователя ввести число еще раз и вернуть введенное значение только в том случае, если оно корректно. И в этом случае можно обойтись без исключений:

```
double Account::ReadPercent()
{
    double per { 0 };

    do 
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter per value (value should be in range [0..100])\n";
        std::cin >> per;

        if (per < 0 || per>100)
        {
            std::cout << "This is a invalid value!\n";
        }
    }
    while (per < 0 || per > 100);

    return per;
}
```

Использование исключений будет уместно, когда исключение будет обрабатываться где-то дальше, например, в вызывающем функцию `ReadPercent` коде

```
double Account::ReadPercent()
{
    double per;

    std::cin >> per;
    if (per < 0 || per>100)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("This is a invalid value!\n");
    }

    return per;
}
```

...

```
Account acc;
double per { 0 };
try 
{
    per = acc.ReadPercent();
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double Account::ReadPercent(std::istream& is)
{
    double per;    
    is >> per;
    if (per < 0 || per>100)        
        throw std::range_error("This is a invalid value!\n");      
    return per;
}
```

Так будет лучше. Таким образом аргумент вашей функции подсказывает пользователью, что будет ввод из потока, плюс вы можете выполнить ввод не только с консоли, но и из файла, любого другого потока... Плюс вызов может осуществлятся с приложения, где вообше нет консольного

Во вторых, генерировать логично именно `std::range_error`, поскольку это исключение генерируется при выходе `за границ во время выполнения`, что и наблюдается в вашем случаи.

И, наконец, исключение выбрасываются для клиентов(вызывающей функции) этой функции, чтобы клиент мог бы обработать исключительную  ситуацию так, как ему захочется. Обработав сразу же, вы делаете тоже самое, что и просто написали бы `else { cout << "std::range_error "; }`